# Unity3d can't assemble android build (.aab) with "split application binary" (tried Unity 2021 LTS & Unity 2022 LTS)

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm trying to build an android project (aab), inside firebase, GA, appmetrica, purchasing, revenue cat, native review and what not.

In short, everything is built without problems if you build without split application binary. With this checkbox it is not built in any way.

Initially everything is on version 2021, but just for the sake of the test we updated to 2022 (there is a new gradle). In 2022 the errors are different, but also does not build the build.

Very much looking for some help

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: D:\Work\Projects\Hypercore-shooter 2022 (temp)\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\revenuecat\purchasesunity\PurchasesWrapper.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':launcher:packageReleaseBundle'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.PackageBundleTask$BundleToolWorkAction
   > Both modules 'base' and 'UnityDataAssetPack' contain asset entry 'assets/UnityServicesProjectConfiguration.json'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 16s

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

We tried to build using 2021.3.29f1. Everything work when "split application binary" disabled, and doesn't work (doesn't build) if it's set to true.

Same thing about Unity 2022.3.7f1. No ideas how to fix it :(